# форматированный вывод double

Tags: c++

double d = 1000000000000000000;
Нужно чтобы на экран вывелось это число именно в таком виде без плавающей точки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С++ стиль:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
std::cout.precision(0); //0 - число символов после точки
std::cout << d;
```

C стиль:

```
printf("%.0lf",d);  //%.Klf - K - число символов после точки, в данном случае 0
```

Comment: +1, но обратите внимание, что число 1000000000000000001 выведется _точно так же_: http://ideone.com/1SEHpO (потому что http://ideone.com/qJOA2I)

Comment: @VlaD, можете пояснить подробно здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/191857/